# TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function, i don't know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I got this error when i run this project: "TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function". i don't understand why, also if i try to do

```
this.setState({
      this.state.posts.push(0),
    })
```

or even without `this.setState()`:
`this.state.posts.push(0)`
this is a very banal code but i don't understand why i got this error. This is my code:

```
import FbPost from './components/fb_post';
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    posts : [0]
  }
  
  WritePost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      posts: this.state.posts.push(0),
    })
    
    console.log(this.state.posts);
    
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="Posts">
          {this.state.posts.map((value, index) => (
            <FbPost />
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.WritePost}>Clicca</button>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Array.push() returns the new length of the array. So even if pushing directly to a state array were allowed in react, you can't use that as new value. To push to a state array in React, use `this.setState({ posts: [...this.state.posts, newElement] });`

Comment: Also, to better understand the error: `this.state.posts.map is not a function` basically translates to: `this.state.posts is not an Array` (and therefore has no `.map()` method). Once you realize that, your code becomes much easier to debug.

Comment: thanks man! Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't worry, I was stumped by JS error messages for years. They make perfect sense and seem without alternative once you understand what they mean, but before that, it's all Greek ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`array.prototype.push` returns the new length of the array that was just pushed into. You are not only mutating your state object, but then changing the state type invariant entirely, from `array` to `number`. This causes the `.map` function to fail and throw the error you see.

```
WritePost = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    posts: this.state.posts.push(0),
  })

  console.log(this.state.posts);

}
```

Additionally, since React state updates are asynchronous, you can't console log the state *right after* enqueueing a state update and expect it to be the *next* state. Use `componentDidUpdate` to log state updates.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to shallow copy the previous state and append the new element.

```
WritePost = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    posts: [...prevState.posts, 0],
  }));
}
```